# How do I enter text into multidimentional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a text file of

alex NAME

London CITY

England COUNTRY

I want to store it in a multidimentional array

```
 string[,] tokened = new string[3, 2];
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        string[] input = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\abc.txt");
        foreach (string line in input)
        {
            foreach (var row in line.Split('\n'))
            {
                foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(' '))
                {
                    tokened[i, j] = Convert.ToString((col.Trim()));
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
```

i have written this code but wouldn't work.

Comment: `but wouldn't work.` Why? any error? exception? unexpected result?

Comment: Your first split needs to read line by line. See the MSD for this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format. on this line 
     tokened[i, j] = Convert.ToString(int.Parse((col.Trim())));

Comment: Why don't you put a break-point on that line and inspect the value who throws the exception. (Or print the value of `col.Trim()`  before calling `int.Parse` to catch the bug.)  .

Comment: What have you tried? Did that work? What went wrong? Did you get any errors? You need to include this information in your questions. Please read this guide to make sure your questions are as answer-able as possible: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: alright. The thing is row is getting alex but col is also getting the value of alex. Column wouldn't fetch NAME value.

Comment: BTW: what is the use of `int.Parse` when there is no number in your input?

Comment: Then it says IndexOutofBound error.

Comment: I have updated the code a bit. Now still it is stuck on that error IndexOutofBound. and col value is incorrect

Comment: This is full of mistakes; `File.ReadAllLines` already splits newlines so either your text file is wrong or `line.Split('\n')` is redundant. You start with `j=0` and you keep incrementing `j` after every column of every row, so after the second column of the first row it will be `2` and overflow the second dimension of `tokened`. Please read [How to Debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
     var numberOfRecords = 3;
        var numberOfFields = 2;
        var columnDelimeter = ' ';
        var lineSeparator = "\r\n\r\n";
        var tokened = new string[numberOfRecords, numberOfFields];
        var input = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"d:\abc.txt");
        var lines = input.Replace(lineSeparator, "|").Split('|').ToArray();
        //loop through rows
        for (var row = 0; row < lines.Length; row++)
        {
            //split the columns with a space
            var cols = lines[row].Split(columnDelimeter).ToArray();
            for(var col = 0; col < numberOfFields; col++)
            {
                tokened[row, col] = cols[col];
            }
        }
```